# Google Colab, Pandas and .DataFrame - How to skip rows?

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I am trying a tutorial on Colab and I am trying to skip the first row as it contains
Date information that is not required. The headers or column labels are in the second row. Usually I do this `df = read_csv("FILENAME", skiprows=1)`.

The tutorial has me using `df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows)`. If I try to put a skiprows=1 it comes up with a type error (from_records() got an unexpected keyword argument 'skiprows')

Any suggestions appreciated, I've Googled it, searched the documentation and looked for other code samples.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the doc [skiprows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) does not take a `skiprows` argument.

`data, index=None, exclude=None, columns=None, coerce_float=False, nrows=None`

Your `rows` object should already be sliced they way you want before using `from_records`.

Given what you have, you should be using
`df = read_csv("FILENAME", skiprows=1)`

Comment: Thank you for your input, I am using a Google Sheet and loading the data directly into pandas with it. The tutorial is using .from_records. I normally use the read_csv/skiprows=1 when dealing with my files (which are csv).  Stay safe and healthy.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `.from_records`. then your data is already setup row-wise. You can simply use indexing to skip the first n rows:

```
rows = [
    [1, "a", "cat"],
    [5, "b", "dog"],
    [10, "c", "elephant"]
]

new_rows = rows[1:] # use indexing to skip the first row
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(new_rows)
```

Comment: Thank you for your input and advise, appreciated. Stay healthy and safe.

Answer (score 0):

`from_records` works with `np.array`'s where usually there is no header. If you need to process csv file - use read_csv, if you use `np.array` with headers in it - skip them with array slicing:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([
... ["header",1,2,3,4,5],
... ["header",1,2,3,4,5],
... ["header",1,2,3,4,5],
... ["header",1,2,3,4,5],
... ])
>>> arr[:, 1:]
array([['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
       ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
       ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
       ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']], dtype='<U6')
```

Same if you have array like `[["index","index","index"], [1,2,3],[1,2,3][1,2,3]]`, just do `array[1:]` and you'll get what you want

Comment: I am loading data from a Google Sheet and trying to manipulate it after that. I have used pandas for only about 2 months and got really used to read_csv . I will look into numpy more as I have no experience other than  importing it.

Comment: And thank you for your input and advice, stay healthy and safe.

Comment: In this case you may want to take a look at [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-import-google-sheets-data-into-a-pandas-dataframe-using-googles-api-v4-2020-f50e84ea4530)